# Spring Boot MongoDB: reactivestreams driver always uses the default localhost instead of URI

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-mongo-java

I have a java Spring-Boot application that connects to an external MongoDB server. Whenever I start the application I see two clusters created:

```
[    Test worker] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}`
[    Test worker] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Cluster created with settings {hosts=[<mymongo server address>:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms'}
```

and after that it throws an error:

```
[127.0.0.1:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 127.0.0.1:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.AsynchronousSocketChannelStream$OpenCompletionHandler.failed(AsynchronousSocketChannelStream.java:116) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.0.5.jar:na]...
```

I have no MongoDB on localhost.

My Mongo client configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

  @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.uri}")
  private String mongoUri;

  @Bean
  public MongoClient mongoClient() {
      return MongoClients.create(mongoUri);
  }

  @Override
  protected String getDatabaseName() {
      return "db_test";
  }
}
```

Spring-boot start class:

```
@EnableReactiveMongoRepositories
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {MongoAutoConfiguration.class, MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class,
    MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration.class, EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class})
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(basePackages = "com.netsurf")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class ConfigurationServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigurationServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

in application.properties I have:
`spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://my_mongo_server_address`

Comment: Why are you configuring it yourself instead of letting Spring Boot do it for you?

Comment: I used the examples from MongoDB documentation: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.1/driver-reactive/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/

Comment: Well don't. Just ditch your own configuration, remove the excludes and run your application. There is no need to exclude it as Spring Boot will configure it for you. Which is what the `MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration` is for (which you excluded).

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. But shouldn't it worked with manual configuration also?

Answer (score 0):

There are valid use cases where we may want to configure our own `MongoClient` bean. For example, when we need to configure a custom SSL context or if we want to adjust timeout values.

I have seen a couple of problems with the creation of a `MongoClient` bean. Typically these lead to the following error message:

> Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ...

This message is a bit confusing and hard to debug, because its often not clear what the problem is. But basically it means there is a problem connecting to the MongoDb cluster. If you have multiple MongoClient beans active, it can happen that one successfully connects and the other keeps throwing exceptions. Also note, that this bean will keep throwing exceptions in the background that you will only see if you increase the log level for `org.mongodb` to `DEBUG`.

From what I understand the following can be sources of trouble when we manually configure a bean:

1. Make sure that the `MongoClient` instance is from the correct package and double check your imports. Both the `sync` driver (`org.mongodb.client` and the `reactivestreams` driver (`org.mongodb.reactivestreams.client`) have a class with the same name. If the wrong one is created you will see hard to diagnose error messages.
2. It appears depending on which driver we use, we should exclude the auto-configuration of the respective other classes from Spring Boot. For example, if we use the `reactivestreams` driver, then we want to exclude the `MongoAutoConfiguration.class` so that the synchronous MongoClient bean is not created. In particular, if we reuse the `spring.data.mongodb.*` family of properties and don't exclude the autoconfiguration classes, then our own `MongoClient` bean only disables one of the two autoconfiguration classes which detects the respective bean. But the other autoconfiguration one will happily continue to create a bean from the other driver.
3. Both the `sync` driver and the `reactivestreams` driver use the logger prefix `org.mongodb.driver.cluster` which makes it quite hard to see which driver a certain log message came from. Even, if we turn up the log level to DEBUG. You can try to place break points into the constructors of:

- org.mongodb.client.MongoClientImpl (sync driver)
- org.mongodb.reactivestreams.MongoClientImpl (reactive stream driver)

to see exactly which client is being created.

If you have two `MongoClient` and they are from different drivers, then you can have a condition where the application seems to work fine and is using one of the `MongoClients` while a second one is active that keeps throwing exceptions in the background.